# How to add list to column by SQLite kotlin query android

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, sql-insert

I have 5 columns in the database, 4 of which I fill out a request from the network. I'm trying to add data to the database specifically in these 4 columns via `@QUERY`, because when trying to do this via @Insert `(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)`, the value in the 5th column is set to default.

I would like to insert the entire list into the column through sqlite, that is, into the `"id" List <Int>`, in the `"first_name" List <String>`, etc. ? Is this possible, if so, what would the correct syntax look like? At the moment I am filling in the data through a for loop.

Here is the request:

```
@Query("INSERT INTO friends_table (id, first_name, last_name, photo) VALUES (:id, :firstName, :lastName, :photo)")

suspend fun insertAll(
        id: Int,
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        photo: String
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For correct working out "@Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)" it is required to mark id with annotation "@PrimaryKey"

You entity model.

```
@Entity
class EmployeeEntity(
        @PrimaryKey
        id: Int,
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        photo: String
)

@Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun insertAll(entities: List<EmployeeEntity>)
```

Link for [primary key](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/PrimaryKey)

Link for [entity](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Entity)

Comment: id was originally annotated with @PrimaryKey.